# Can't move/resize texture in UV Mode

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

For some unknown reason, I can't manipulate my textures while in UV Edit mode (both v2.79 & 2.80.) The texture is applied and displayed on screen, and when I go into UV Edit mode, the UV Map appears over the texture like it should, but then any changes I make to the map have no effect on the applied texture. Resize, rotate, move, the map changes but the texture doesn't and I have no idea why.

I'm trying to edit an old Blender file (probably created using v2.64 but I don't think it matters.) I can't stand the new v2.80 interface (what used to be simple things are now 12-step processes) so I prefer to continue using 2.79.

I'm not a *total* Blender novice, but I'm definitely on the low end of the scale when it comes to knowing why things do what they do.

Any help is appreciated. TIA.

Comment: I'd say you'd really want to explore Blender 2.8, I kept on using Blender 2.7 but then I realized, I am missing so much and now after I moved to Blender 2.8 I never want to think about 2.79 :D

Also could you share your blender file to check if that's okay?

Comment: I'd suggest sharing some screenshots of the problem you are having so we can see what might be a solution then - description only goes so far.

Comment: Thanks for the reply(s). I've uploaded a screenshot [here](https://i.postimg.cc/8Cptk0F7/uvmap-no-change.jpg). Changes to the UV map produce no change to the applied texture on the right.

Comment: Can you share your blend file, screenshots aren't looking enough!

Comment: I temporarily uploaded the file [here](https://mega.nz/#!fJsHDIhQ!z2-R3BWVZjRxklRPdGVSr-IAH3o4R4tRddd57Tsn-6c). Thanks.